# Count frequency of string in string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have list of usernames (string). Each name
cn[i] will have several skills attached to it:

```
cn[0] has: "text1, text2, text3"
cn[1] has: "text2, text4, text6"
cn[2] has: "text6, text8"
cn[2] has: "text11, text8, text1, text4, text2"
```

etc.

Now I need to count how many skills in total and each skill how many people have.
So I think it will contain following steps:

```
1. add text1, text2, ... to an array (I don't know how to get each string and get rid of the comma "'")
2. suppose we have 

    string[] stringArray = { "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text6", ... };
```

we can check the frequency by:

```
foreach (string x in stringArray)
{
    if (x.Contains(stringToCheck))
    {
        // increase the number of count
    }
}
```

3. I don't know how to stick that count number to each skill then later we can display it.
I am thinking of something like Map map  = new HashMap();

Comment: I gather you are looking for two things. The first is the number of occurrences of each skill across all users. The second is the same figure, but by user. Is this correct?

Comment: By skills in total, do you mean how many distinct skills there are?

Comment: yes, distinct skills, no repeat skill (string).

Comment: Please rewrite your question more explicitly. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. By the way, the thing that's like a `HashMap` is `Dictionary` in `C#`. What would it mean to count skill occurrence within each user? Aren't a single user's skills distinct already? Is a filtering step required? Be clear! Be explicit! I'll make another attempt to help at that point. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) and [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) extension methods found in `System.Linq` to perform the task:

```
using System.Linq;

var frequency = cn
    .SelectMany(u => u.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None))
    .GroupBy(s => s)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

var numberOfSkills = frequency.Count;

var numberOfUsersWithSkillOne = frequency["SkillOne"];
```

Comment: I didn't have string Array at step 2. How to form it ? And I don't see any place that it will store frequency to each skill in your code. sorry if I miss some points...

Comment: I've offered a simplified solution you might prefer. Please accept the answer if you like the solution, or feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: Yes, certainly I like the simpler answer. Let me check your solution. How could I form the skill sets from each user skill set? Only after that I can count frequency right ?

Comment: Do you mean: (u => u.Split(new string[] { ", " }, where "u" instead of "s"

Comment: @user1314404 the letter doesn't matter, inside the bracket it just a variable name.  As long as the same letter is used before and after the `=>` its fine, you could use any variable name here.  Likewise the group by could just as easily be `GroupBy(u => u)` or `GroupBy(row => row)`

Comment: @BobVale OP was referring to a real typo I made. I had `u => s...` instead of `u => u...`. I've already edited my answer, is all.

Comment: Why I tried your method and it has red underline error: "char does not contain a definition for 'Split' ...." ?

Comment: and for my understanding each cn[i] has different skills, we need to extract from each of them, so where is the final set of all skills stored in ?

Comment: Your question is really hard for me to understand. I was under the impression that `cn` was a `string[]` with skill strings separated by `", "`. Please clarify your question before asking why my answer doesn't work.

Comment: cn was a string like you said. But not only one cn. several cn[1], cn[2], ..cn[i]. Each of them have a set of skill strings separated by ",". I need to combine all that string into one set of skill where no skill repeating twice.

Comment: I already stated very clear in my question that the final string to process is stringArray  (which you called "cn"). But we need to form stringArray "cn" from cn[0], cn[1], cn[2] etc, and if each skill only put to cn once. How to form it is also a part of my question.

Comment: Although I am not fully satisfy with this answer but it give me some suggestions for me to seek for the full solution, so I will choose your code as my answer. Thanks for your help!